# c# loop duplicate records inserted

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So im working on a proof of concept adventure and what im trying to do is loop through html and find all the links and save the link in mysql using C#. The finding the links part is working perfectly but when i go to save the links in a table they are be duplicated incrementally.  Example below

Records in table:
1:1
1:2
1:2
1:3
1:3
1:3
1:4
1:4
1:4
1:4
etc...

pages table:

```
    | page_id | page_url        | date_added |
    ------------------------------------------
    | 1       | "http://bla.com |            |
```

links table:

```
    | link_id | link_page_id | date_added |
    ---------------------------------------
```

code to get the links:

```
    private static void getLinks(string contents, string url)
    {
        HtmlDocument html = new HtmlDocument();
        html.LoadHtml(contents);

        HtmlNodeCollection links = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

        foreach(HtmlNode link in links)
        {
           foreach(HtmlAttribute attr in link.Attributes)
            {
                if(attr.Name == "href")
                {
                    saveLinks(url, attr.Value);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Code to save the links:

```
    private static void saveLinks(string url, string link)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(url + " - " + link);
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO 
                                    sites.links(
                                        links_page_id, 
                                        link
                                    )
                                SELECT
                                    p.page_id,
                                    @link
                                FROM 
                                    sites.links l
                                RIGHT JOIN 
                                    sites.pages p
                                ON p.page_url = @url";
            cmd.Prepare();

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@url", url);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@link", link);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failure: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

On my console output im getting the expected number of links with no duplicates and i have tested the query in mysql and all seemed good.  Its probably something stupid that im overlooking but i cannot seem to find what im doing wrong.  So any help would be awesome.

Comment: Maybe it's your `RIGHT JOIN` I would expect it to be just a simple Inner Join but I do not know your actual table structure.. or you can do select Distinct

Comment: I have tried an inner join with no luck.  I updated the question with the table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get `page_id` by its url, you needn't join with `sites.links`

```
          cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO 
                                sites.links(
                                    links_page_id, 
                                    link
                                )
                            SELECT
                                p.page_id,
                                @link
                            FROM 
                                sites.pages p
                            WHERE p.page_url = @url";
```

Comment: Haha your completely right.  I cannot believe i missed i was doing that.   Its been along day.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You formatting is strange... this is what I'm used to:

```
 SELECT p.page_id, @link
 FROM sites.links l
 RIGHT JOIN sites.pages p ON p.page_url = @url";
```

so here are all the things that don't make sense.  The table you are selecting from (sites.links) is not used anywhere in the query, which also means it is not used in the RIGHT JOIN which means this is not not a right join but a cross join.

What exactly are you trying to do, I'm very lost.

Maybe if you show what input you are getting and what output you expect that could help.

Comment: I'm trying to get the page id from the pages table that match's the URL and then insert that page id and link string into the links table.

Comment: @jgetner - I see serg showed you not to use the join at all.  It seemed to me that might be the case but I wasn't sure.